# Referencing Variables through Strings in R

Tags: r, variables, reference

I am trying to call variables in R by using a string and I am running the following command.

```
ls(Names)
"John" "Ryan" "Danielle" "Jim" .....
i="Names"
j="John"
get(i)$get(j)
```

Why doesn't the two `get` commands, seperated by the `$` work?

Comment: So `Names` is an environment then?

Comment: Hi, yes it is! Sorry, forgot to add that. Always have a problem with combining string elements into functions/R calls, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can make something like this work (though not sure why you would) like:

```
#Names <- as.environment(list(John = 1, Ryan = 2, Danielle = 3, Jim = 4))
i <- "Names"
j <- "John"
get(i)[[j]]
#[1] 1
```

`get(j)` errors out when run separately, as there is no `John` object in the global environment.

```
get(j)
#Error in get(j) : object 'John' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

@thelatemail's answer is preferable, but if you really want to use `get` twice, you can do

```
get(j, envir = get(i))
```